# в массив добавляется только 1 элемент

Tags: php, массивы

В массиве errMsg содержится только 1 первый элемент. добавление остальных через push_array игнорируется. Подскажите с чем это может быть связано, пожалуйста

```
$errMsg = [];
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['button-reg'])){
    $admin = 0;
    $login = trim($_POST['login']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $pass1 = trim($_POST['password1']);
    $pass2 = trim($_POST['password2']);

    if($login === '' || $email === '' || $pass2 === ''){
        array_push($errMsg, 'Не всі поля заповненні');
    }
    elseif(mb_strlen($login, 'UTF8') < 4){
        array_push($errMsg, 'Логін повинен бути більше 4х символів');
    }
    elseif($pass1 !==  $pass2){
        array_push($errMsg, 'Пароль у полях повинен бути однаковим');
    }
    else{
        $existence = selectOne('users', ['email' => $email]);
        if (!empty($existence['email']) && $existence['email'] === $email){
            array_push($errMsg, 'Користувач з цією поштою вже зареєстрований');
        }
        else{
            $pass = password_hash($pass1, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $user = [
                'admin' => $admin,
                'username' => $login,
                'email' => $email,
                'password' => $pass
            ];
            $id = insert('users', $user); 
            $user = selectOne('users', ['id' => $id]); 

            authUser($user);

        }  
    }
    test($errMsg)  ;
}
```

[image: Результат:]

Comment: правила общения подразумевают ещё формулирование просьбы, обычно со словом,"пожалуйста"

Comment: Извините, мысли рассеиваются, не пришло в голову

Comment: Замените elseif на if - сейчас выполняется только одна ветка

Comment: @Сергей что за бред? Это база знаний, а не уроки вежливости. И вообще https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/93/191482 , ознакомьтесь

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, можно, конечно, считать "бредом" слово "пожалуйста"*, но вот догадываться, что автор хочет получить на выходе в текстах без конкретного вопроса - точно странное занятие. Варианты (как минимум их два здесь): он хочет подсказку, он хочет полное решение. А есть ещё масса вопросов, где вообще не понять, что автор хочет. И получает он в ответ не менее для него непонятный шаблон ответа от Духа сообщества (которые я и буду в дальнейшем использовать "во избежание").

Comment: @Сергей так вот и надо писать не про "пожалуйста", а про то, что в текст вопроса необходимо добавить, собственно, вопрос, в чëм заключается проблема и т.д., т.к. в текущем виде не ясно, что не так и дать ответ невозможно ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯